# PySpark - Getting list of dicts and converting its keys/values to columns

Tags: json, pyspark

I have the following json (located in my local file system in `path_json`):

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@hisemail.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "dict_of_columns": [
            {
                "column_name": "hobbie",
                "columns_value": "guitar"
            },
            {
                "column_name": "book",
                "columns_value": "1984"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary",
        "email": "mary@heremail.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "dict_of_columns": [
            {
                "column_name": "language",
                "columns_value": "Python"
            },
            {
                "column_name": "job",
                "columns_value": "analyst"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, this is a nested json.
I am reading it with the following command:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(path_json)
```

Ok. Now, it produces me the following DataFrame:

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------+------+----+
|dict_of_columns                     |email              |gender|name|
+------------------------------------+-------------------+------+----+
|[[hobbie, guitar], [book, 1984]]    |john@hisemail.com  |Male  |John|
|[[language, Python], [job, analyst]]|mary@heremail.com  |Female|Mary|
+------------------------------------+-------------------+------+----+
```

I want to know if there is a way to produces the following dataframe:

```
+----+-----------------+------+------+-------+--------+----+
|book|email            |gender|hobbie|job    |language|name|
+----+-----------------+------+------+-------+--------+----+
|1984|john@hisemail.com|Male  |guitar|null   |null    |John|
|null|mary@heremail.com|Female|null  |analyst|Python  |Mary|
+----+-----------------+------+------+-------+--------+----+
```

A few comments:

- My real data has thousands and thousands of lines
- I don't know all the `column_name` in my dataset (there are many of them)
- `email` is unique for each line, so it can be used as key if a join is necessary. I tried this approach before: create a main dataframe with columns `[name,gender,email]` and other dataframes for each row containing the dictionaries. But without success (and it doesn`t have good performance).

Thanks you so much!

Comment: The data is a semi structured one, hence it is in json format. Its not advisable to explode all columns like this, as it might result in a sparse data., with lot of Null values.